# multiple NVIDIA graphics card and GPU problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am assisting someone with a problem they are having with the video card and GPUs on their machine.

```
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110BGL [Tesla K40c] (rev a1)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK110BGL [Tesla K40c] (rev a1)
84:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K620] (rev a2)
```

The Quadro video card is working with a nouveau driver but the Tesla GPUs are not recognized/working. When I try to install a NVidia driver and reboot the video card won't work and I have to purge the NVidia driver from the command line. In addition, nothing appears when I type NVidia-smi on any account after installing the driver.

The machine had been working with the GPUs and something "happened" where now they do not. I do not have the information for how this problem initially presented itself.

How can I install the proper drivers for the Tesla GPUs while also having a driver that supports the video card? I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2.